# Cross cluster analysis of categorical data in R

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data

How do we perform cross cluster analysis in R. Most of my data has categorical variables {variable Marital Status (married, single, divorced); variable Education (tertiary, secondary, primary, etc.); and the variables Credit, Mortgage, and Loan (yes, no)}? The only interval variable in my data set is the Age.

Comment: Questions that are only about how to use software are generally off topic here. If you have a machine learning question about clustering categorical data, please edit to clarify.

Comment: I think this person is very early in learning.  I don't think they are asking R only.  I think they are asking "how do I think about this".  It is exceptionally broad, but I think they are asking for "starting points" to enter the subject.  I don't think they know the questions they could ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible duplicate [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112567/how-do-i-create-clusters-with-a-completely-categorical-data), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24540/clustering-of-mixed-type-data-with-r) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187595/clustering-with-categorical-and-numeric-data). 
Distance-based clustering algorithms can handle categorical data. So you can implement clustering from a dissimilarity matrix.

First, you have to compute all the pairwise dissimilarities (distances) between observations in the data set (with `daisy()`). 
Then, you can run your clustering algorithm (with `agnes()`, `CrossClustering()`,...).

Here is an example.

```
library(cluster)
data(flower)
str(flower)
flower <- flower[, 1:6] # just to keep only categorial variables
# Dissimilarity matrix matrix
distm <- daisy(flower, metric = "gower", stand = FALSE)
distm

# Hierarchical agglomerative clustering (HAC)
hac <- agnes(distm, diss = TRUE)
hac$order
plot(hac)

# Partial clustering algorithm with automatic estimation of the number of 
# clusters and identification of outliers
library(CrossClustering)
cross.clust <- CrossClustering(distm, k.w.min = 2, k.w.max = 5,
                               k.c.max = 6, out = TRUE)
cross.clust$Cluster.list
```

Comment: Thank you ANG. That was really helpful. And sorry if my question looks similar to others.

Comment: `Error in CrossClustering(distm, k.w.min = 2, k.w.max = 5, k.c.max = 6,  : 
  could not find function "CrossClustering"` I tried to correct last two lines. Is this correct code? `cross.clust <- cc_crossclustering(distm, k_w_min = 2, k_w_max = 5, k2_max = 6, out = TRUE)
cross.clust`